# Can I have ant output an equivalent script?

Tags: java, ant

Is there any way that I can have ant output a file of all the commands that a given run executes? I'd like to be able to run the script, and it would build the project as though it were built by ant.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you trying to run an ant script and have only the commands that were executed logged to a new shell script/batch file that can be run separately? Or just to a smaller ant script?

Comment: @highlycaffeinated: I understand the question to mean broadly the former - i.e. invoke Ant with a certain switch/parameter, and it spits out a batch/shell script file that performs the same actions that Ant would itself.  So instead of copying fileA to fileB, for example, Ant would echo `cp fileA fileB\n` to its output.

Comment: Do you really mean commands (like example above) or that it should output the names of targets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Ant doesn't always work through the shell so there are not necessarily commands there to be logged.

[`org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform`](http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/ja/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/Task.html#perform%28%29) is not required to use `java.lang.Runtime` to spawn processes.  It can use `java.io` to manipulate files via classes that have no `main` method.